# ¿Cómo recargar página si detecta error con JS?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Me aparece un error al cargar un plugin en Wordpress. 
Pero he notado que se arregla si vuelvo a cargar la página. 
Lo que quiero hacer es hacer un código que si detecta el error, entonces force que se vuelva a cargar la página.

También pensé que siempre que entrara por primera vez a la página recargara de manera forzada, e hice algo así, pero no funcionó.

```
        var pagina_cargada = false;

    if((location.pathname) == "/contacto.html"){
        while(not pagina_cargada){

            setTimeout(function(){ página_cargada = true }, 400);    

        }

    }
```

*Codigo del error*

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
  at eval (<anonymous>)
  at jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
  at Function.globalEval (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
  at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1)
  at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
  at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
  at slideInNewPage (ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1)
  at j (ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1)
(anonymous) @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
globalEval @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
(anonymous) @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
slideInNewPage @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
setTimeout (async)
j @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
success @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
i @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
fireWith @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
y @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
c @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
loadResource @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
onLinkClicked @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
(anonymous) @ ajax.min.js?ver=4.9.6:1
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
```

Comment: window.location() ????

Comment: tendrías que revisar el plugin, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` puede deberse a que espera un json y recibe un html (el html empieza con `<`)

Answer (score 0):

sirve para recargar la pagina

```
window.location.replace("index.php?accion=index&clase=success");
```